# computation of more random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $U=X+Y$ and $V = Y+ Z$ and $X,Y,Z$ are independent $\operatorname{Bern}(1/3)$ distribution (so $P(X=1)=1/3$ ,$P(X=0)=2/3$ ) what is P(U=V)=?

**answer given by teacher:**

> the chance is equal to $P(U=V)=P(X+Y=Y+Z)=P(X=Z)=P(X = Z = 1)+
> P(X = Z = 0) = P(X = 1)P(Z = 1) + P(X = 0)P(Z = 0)=5/9$

**my question**

how you end up to reach $5/9$ as answer, what is the formula of probability of  multiple discrete variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clearly requires an ASCII-art graph of the probability space:

```
       X=0   X=1
    +-------+---+
    |       |   |
Z=0 |       |   |
    |       |   |
    +-------+---+
Z=1 |       |   |
    +-------+---+
```

You have easily proven that $U=V<=>X=Z$. And since we can only do simple probability multiplications on independent variables, and $U$ and $V$ due to their common reliance on $Y$ are not independent, the correct route is to do all probability calculations using the original independent variables.

Formally we should set up a probability space with a dimension for each independent variable, but in this case since the value of $Y$ has no bearing on the result we can skip that dimension.

As you can see on my beautiful graph the probability that $X=Z=0$ is $4/9=\textrm{P}(X=0)\times\textrm{P}(Z=0)$, and the probability that $X=Z=1$ is $1/9=\textrm{P}(X=1)\times\textrm{P}(Z=1)$. In total $5/9$.